# Hololens 2 app deploys as a 2D window (MRTK 2.8.2.0 - Unity Version : 2020.3.28 f1)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I have been trying to deploy to Hololens 2.

But the app opens in a 2d window inside hololens.

I am following the Hololens 2 fundamental tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-7-exercise-hand-interaction-with-objectmanipulator

Versions are MRTK 2.8.2.0 , Unity Version 2020.3.28 f1 , Visual Studio 2022 17.4

I have been deploying it to remote machine over wifi

Attaching my settings below

[image: XR Management tool]

[image: Player settings - Resolution and Presentation]

[image: Publishing - Supported devices]

I was expecting the HoloLens2 app to start in full/room scale, instead it starts in a window inside HoloLens.

Comment: Works now:

I checked "Initialize XR on Startup" in the XR plugin Management tool

and unchecked "Holographic Remoting app feature group"

Comment: Why not post that as an _answer_ where you can gain reputation. :)

Comment: right! yes doing it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Works now: I checked "Initialize XR on Startup" in the XR plugin Management tool and unchecked "Holographic Remoting app feature group"